# Having trouble .deleteOne by id in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, rest, next.js

I can't delete a specific document by its `id` in MongoDB.
In Next.js, I have this handler to delete a specific chat by `id`.
I was able to delete all documents using `deleteMany` method, but can not delete a specific document by id.

```
export default async function handler(req: any, res: any) {
  try {
    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = client.db("mydb");
    const { chatId } = req.body;

    await db.collection("chats").deleteOne({
      _id: new ObjectId(chatId),
    });

    res.status(200).json({});

  } catch (error) {
    ...
  }
}
```

On pressing a delete button I'm calling a function below:

```
 const handleDeleteSingleChat = async () => {
    await fetch(`/api/database/deleteChat`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        chatId: chatId,
      }),
    });
  };
```

My document in MongoDB looks like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(64747668f6eefac44a882b35);
  ...
}
```

So far I've tried using different REST API methods. I've also tested chatId value and it works fine. I'm not exactly sure what to return in a handler so I just returned an empty object.

Note: I do not get any errors and network shows that fetch function was successful.

Update: I'm able to .deleteOne by writing document's string id directly, the problem is in `chatId` value, but can't figure what.

```
export default async function handler(req: any, res: any) {
  ...

    await db.collection("chats").deleteOne({
      _id: new ObjectId("64747668f6eefac44a882b35"),
    });
  ...
}
```

Comment: "_I've also tested chatId value and it works fine_": do you refer to `chatId` in `const { chatId } = req.body`? I suspect `fetch` misses `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`, in which case your backend would have `chatId` as `undefined`

Comment: I've figured it out. I've included ```headers: { "content-type": "application/json"}``` and changed method to ```POST```. I do not know why ```POST``` method worked here, but ```DELETE``` didn't. If somebody can explain it, it would be really nice. Is it because I didn't specifically filtered ```if request.method == 'post'```. I would love some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fetch` call is very probably missing a content type, so that your body is converted to JSON in the backend:

```js
fetch(`/api/database/deleteChat`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    // Ensure body will be interpreted as JSON by backend
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    chatId: chatId,
  }),
});
```

Furthermore, in the case of `DELETE` method, the id should typically be passed in the URL, rather than in the request body. See [Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)

Looks like Next.js started to ignore the request body in the case of a `DELETE` method only recently, leading to confusion among developers relying on the old behaviour: see [vercel/next.js#49353](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49353)